# Subdirectory on different servers but same sub domain

Tags: iis, domain

I have a subdomain e.g.

```
https://xyz.example.com
```

In IIS I have a subdirectory under this domain on one server:

```
https://xyz.example.com/site1
```

I want to point the subdomain to another ip address on another server e.g.

```
https://xyx.example.com/site2
```

So basically I have two sites using the same subdomain but on different server. Is this possible and if so how do you configure it?

Comment: 1) Learn what terms you should use to describe IIS setup https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis 2) "I want to point the subdomain" but `https://xyz.example.com/site1` is not a subdomain that most people talk about. 3) "another ip address on another server", but `https://xyx.example.com/site2` is not an IP address. So edit the question to make it clear please.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible.
The destination server is defined by the subdomain, not the subdirectory.

A workaround might be to put a reverse proxy server in front of the two servers.
This proxy servers can internally dispatch requests to another web server depending on the subdirectory.
This can work because the subdomain points to the reverse proxy which dispatches the requests.